# Colour-Code the calendar in ALL views in SharePoint 2013 Foundation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, calendar, custom

I followed and completed the tutorials on how to make the events in the calendar colour coated to different categories (see image below)[image: calendar sample v1]

However when I view that calendar on a page which I assume is the preview the colour is the default SharePoint colour. How could I go about inheriting the colour changed made above (see image below).

[image: calendar sample v2]

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing. I figured out how to make the colours display in the preview. Just simply click "modify view" while looking at the "Preview" and change the filter to "**Category** is equal to" [insert text that does not exist in your category column] **NOTHING**  then it will work. Because it will look under Category and look for the value that holds the text NOTHING. I hope this helps someone

[image: Desired Result]